# ConfigurationErrorsException- The process cannot access the file 'c:\eventlog.config' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, event-handling, event-log

Team,

I have this piece of code which invariably ties up itself in a sort of race condition especially when two or more resources are trying to write to eventlog.config file simultaneously. I have googling out several channels but not able to solve this error out. Can anyone help me to modify this code so that i can remove the race condition.

```
private void UpdateLastEventId(IList<EventLogEntry> entries)
    {
        if (entries.Count > 0)
        {
            EventLogEntry lastEntry = entries[entries.Count - 1];

            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var configSettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

            string key = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}|{1}", _eventLogFilter.EventLog, _eventLogFilter.MD5Hash);
            if (configSettings[key] == null)
            {
                configSettings.Add(key, lastEntry.Index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
            else
            {
                configSettings[key].Value = lastEntry.Index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);//Error seems to happen here
        }
    }
```

Comment: have your read the [Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private static readonly object _configLogLock = new object();
    private void UpdateLastEventId(IList<EventLogEntry> entries)
    {
        if (entries.Count > 0)
        {
            EventLogEntry lastEntry = entries[entries.Count - 1];

            lock (_configLogLock)
            {
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                var configSettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

                string key = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}|{1}", _eventLogFilter.EventLog, _eventLogFilter.MD5Hash);
                if (configSettings[key] == null)
                {
                    configSettings.Add(key, lastEntry.Index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
                else
                {
                    configSettings[key].Value = lastEntry.Index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);//Error seems to happen here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you doing with `_configLogLock` once the information has been saved to the .config..? you should dispose of all newly created objects

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My only contention now is as to how to test this lock statement using race condition so as to write to the config file ? In short can you give me ideas as to how to simulate race condition so that i can test the lock statement.

Comment: I would create hundreds of threads that execute UpdateLastEventId and run them in parallel.

Comment: ok..so my UpdateLastEventId is called from the main method. So how do i create a new thread within the main function where the definition of the calling method lies and then do a start. Sorry but i am a bit novice at this